# Chrome Extension Authentication with ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

Im trying to build a chrome extension with ReactJS that also has authentication. Ive followed the google oauth flow here https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/tut_oauth/ and I continuously get undefined on the token. `Welcome.tsx:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAuthToken')`

```
const Welcome = () => {

  const handleAuth = () => {
    console.log('chrome', chrome)
    chrome.identity.getAuthToken({interactive: true}, function(token) {
      console.log(token);
    });
  }

  return( 
  <div>
    <Typography>
        Hello World
    </Typography>
    <Button variant="contained" onClick={handleAuth}>Log In Google</Button>

  </div>
  )
}

export default Welcome;
```

Is this because I need to use this as sort of a background script to handle it? Note my manifest has the `key`  `"permissions": ["identity"],` and the oauth2 configured correctly. Any guidance appreciated